# file upload issue in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, file-upload

I am trying to upload file in asp.net but I am checking file size using jquery. It works fine in all browsers, except IE. below is the code I'm using to verify the file size.

.aspx

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fuAttachment" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" onchange='test('fuAttachment')' />
```

.js

```
function test(controlID) {
    debugger;
    var isSuccess = false;
    var hasFile = $('#' + controlID).val();

    if (hasFile != undefined) {

        var fileSize = ($('#' + controlID)[0].files[0].size / 1024);
        fileSize = (fileSize / 1024);
        var allowSize = 10;
        if (fileSize <= allowSize) {
            isSuccess = true;
        }
    }

    return isSuccess;
}
```

Its not working in ie. Anybody please help me

Comment: Please check if your ie has javascript enabled.

Comment: Define 'not working'. What errors do you get?

Comment: Do you get any errors? Press `F12` in IE, then click on the Console tab.

Comment: @Lloyd: Getting this error. Error: '0.files.0' is null or not an object

Answer (score 2):

IE versions 9 and below does not support the 'files' property.
It does not support selecting multiple files

Comment: I am selecting only one file at a time. Dont want to use multiple files. So is there any way to do it in IE 9 or below version?

Comment: @user968441 : yes you have to use server side validation then only it will be compatible with IE

Answer (score 1):

As Janith has mentioned above up to IE9 is does not support some fileReader related attributes which work fine in other browsers .

if u want to do some file size validation then u have to do some server side scripting , image size validation , uploading , this all will have to be done by server side or else it may not be supported by IE .